# Mockito: Understanding how when().thenThrow() function works

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
when(mockObj.method(param1, param2)).thenReturn(1);
when(mockObj.method(param1, param2)).thenReturn(2);
```

When there are conflicting statements to return the value from a method with same argument list in a mocked object, I observed that the recent when/thenReturn will be returned. So, the below statement will be true.

```
assertEquals(2, mockObj.method(param1, param2));
```

When there are conflicting statements to throw exceptions, the behavior is not the same as above.
For example,

```
@Test(expected = ExceptionTwo.class)
public void testMethod() {
    when(mockObj.method(param1, param2)).thenThrow(ExceptionOne.class);
    when(mockObj.method(param1, param2)).thenThrow(ExceptionTwo.class);
    mockObj.method(param1, param2);
}
```

This test case failed. Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512245/calling-mockito-when-multiple-times-on-same-object This seems to provide a few more insights along with the answers given below!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first case, as the document referred [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing_consecutive_calls):

```
Warning : if instead of chaining .thenReturn() calls, 
multiple stubbing with the same matchers or arguments is used, 
then each stubbing will override the previous one.
```

So the second will override the first one. Hence, return 2.
In other case, you can refer [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy):

```
when(mock.foo()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());

//Impossible: the exception-stubbed foo() method is called so RuntimeException is thrown.
when(mock.foo()).thenReturn("bar");

//You have to use doReturn() for stubbing:
doReturn("bar").when(mock).foo();
```

When you use when..thenReturn, the stubbed method will be called. The first time you didn't observe it because it is called on the mocked object. But when you write `when` for the second time, then we have some behavior for `mock.foo()` (you set it previously to throw Exception). Hence, the second when(..) statement throws the exception in your case. So you should use doThrow().when(..).method(...) instead.

Comment: For the second part of the question, you said when(..).thenReturn actually calls the method. I think it is only true for spy objects and not for mocked objects (using mock).

Answer (score 2):

The first example is as per design, you can refer to the below link for more details.

https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing_consecutive_calls

In the second example, the exception was raised while trying to register for stub one more time `when(mockObj.method(param1,param2)).thenThrow(ExceptionTwo.class);`. Kindly note that it's not due to statement `mockObj.method(param1, param2);`.

In my opinion, there might be actual method call while second `when.thenThrow` statement is executed. If you want to have different exceptions for subsequent calls, you can merge into one statement `when(mockObj.method(param1, param2)).thenThrow(ExceptionOne.class, ExceptionTwo.class);`

Comment: Thanks for identifying that it's the second throw statement which is actually throwing the exception in the first when(..).thenThrow() statement.